# jquery ui slider not being disabled on click and drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I click on the handle of the slider and drag it, it will be disabled but it will still slide. What's wrong with the disabled function?

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
    var prevValue=100;
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 50,
        disabled: false,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", true );
            setTimeout(function(){
     $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );   

    },2000);
            if (prevValue>ui.value){
                ui.value= prevValue-50;
            }else{
                ui.value= prevValue+50;
            }
            prevValue=ui.value;

            $( "#zomlevel" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
            $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", prevValue );
            $('#slider').trigger(e);
            }
    });


    $( "#zomlevel" ).val($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );


});
```

But when I click on the slider then release it will be disabled. How can I make it totally disabled on click and drag.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/endl3ss/jNwww/24/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have this line in your code?

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );   

},2000);
```

Take that out and it stays disabled. Otherwise, it will re-enable after 2 seconds

Comment: That is to set a delay of 2 seconds to the slider so it can be enable again after each slide. The problem is the slider is still sliding even if it is disabled when on drag mode.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the goal then. Do you want the slider to be disabled immediately when you pick it up? The slide method is only called when you put down the slider